# How to find the matrix $\left [ f \right ]_{E_{3}}, \left [ f \right ]_{B}, \left [ f \right ]_{B}^{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Given the linear map $f:\;\mathbb{R}^{3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{3}$ and two basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}:$
$$B= \left \{ b_{1}= \left ( 1, 3, 3 \right ), b_{2}= \left ( -3, 6, 5 \right ), b_{3}= \left ( 1, 2, 2 \right ) \right \}$$
$$C= \left \{ c_{1}= \left ( 2, 0, 3 \right ), c_{2}= \left ( -5, -1, -5 \right ), c_{3}= \left ( 1, 0, 1 \right ) \right \}$$
Let $f\left ( b_{1} \right )= \left ( -5, 6, 4 \right ), f\left ( b_{2} \right )= \left ( -8, 5, 2 \right )$ and $f\left ( b_{3} \right )= \left ( -9, -2, -5 \right )\!.$ Find $\left [ f \right ]_{B}, \left [ f \right ]_{B}^{C}$ and $\left [ f \right ]_{E_{3}}\!.$

Let the basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ be $E_{3}= \left \{ e_{1}= \left ( 1, 0, 0 \right ), e_{2}= \left ( 0, 1, 0 \right ), e_{3}= \left ( 0, 0, 1 \right ) \right \}.$
I only can find the matrix $\left [ f \right ]_{E_{3}}.$  Well, we have
$$f\left ( b_{1} \right )= f\left ( 1, 3, 3 \right )= f\left ( e_{1}+ 3e_{2}+ 3e_{3} \right )= f\left ( e_{1} \right )+ 3f\left ( e_{2} \right )+ 3f\left ( e_{3} \right )= \left ( -5, 6, 4 \right )$$
$$f\left ( b_{2} \right )= f\left ( -3, 6, 5 \right )= f\left ( -3e_{1}+ 6e_{2}+ 5e_{3} \right )= -3f\left ( e_{1} \right )+ 6f\left ( e_{2} \right )+ 5f\left ( e_{3} \right )= \left ( -8, 5, 2 \right )$$
$$f\left ( b_{3} \right )= f\left ( 1, 2, 2 \right )= f\left ( e_{1}+ 2e_{2}+ 2e_{3} \right )= f\left ( e_{1} \right )+ 2f\left ( e_{2} \right )+ 2f\left ( e_{3} \right )= \left ( -9, -2, -5 \right )$$
$$\Rightarrow\left\{\begin{matrix} f\left ( e_{1} \right )= \left ( -17, -18, -23 \right )\\ f\left ( e_{2} \right )= \left ( -79, -89, -112 \right )\\ f\left ( e_{3} \right )= \left ( 83, 97, 121 \right ) \end{matrix}\right.\Rightarrow\left [ f \right ]_{E_{3}}= \begin{pmatrix} -17 & -79 & 83\\ -18 & -89 & 97\\ -23 & -112 & 121 \end{pmatrix}$$
I don't know how to find $\left [ f \right ]_{B}$ and $\left [ f \right ]_{B}^{C}.$ I need to the help. Thanks a real lot !

Comment: In the case where you don't know how to begin, you should include in your question *every* aspect about the problem that you do understand. This accomplishes several things: (1) It shows everyone you made a serious attempt to start solve the problem, (2) It will give you a better understanding of where you're stuck, and (3) in many cases cases this kind of exercise gets you unstuck and able to progress towards a solution.

Comment: @AaronHendrickson I added something, I don't think that's an attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to perform a change of basis you could use transition matrices. In order to compute $[f]_B$ there exists a matrix $B$ such that $[f]_B = B\cdot [f]_{E_3}$. Furthermore there exists also a matrix $C$ such that $[f]_B^C = B\cdot [f]_{E_3} \cdot C$. Try to find out more, maybe consulting a book on linear algebra.